# MySQL insert record

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have this SQL query:

```
insert into messages 
(message, hash, date_add) 
values
('message', 'hash', NOW()) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE
```

hash is unique, what is wrong with query? i got the error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE' at line 1`

Comment: There is no ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE, only ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. You probably mean INSERT IGNORE as Frosty Z pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/insert.html) the syntax should be :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO messages (message, hash, date_add)
  VALUES('message', 'hash', NOW());
```

Comment: and where i must put 'ON DUPLICATE KEY '?

Comment: According to the doc, you don't need to, since putting `IGNORE` just after `INSERT` should be equivalent to what you want to do by adding `ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE` at the end.